# DynamicsCrm - Retrieve Multiple is not supported

Tags: c#, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

I´m developing a data-extraction tool that gets data out of DynamicsCrm.
I have a few tables tough where i get the following exception:

```
Additional information: The 'RetrieveMultiple' method does not support entities of type 'mailboxstatistics'.
```

Reading online, using fetchxml is supposed to be the solution.
For me, it looks like i´m already using fetchxml.
My code:

```
    private static EntityCollection RequestEntityCollection(String FetchXML, Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection c)
    {
        using (OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(c))
        {                  
                EntityCollection r = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(FetchXML));
                return r;
        }
    }
```

I´m currently using the CRM2013 SDK so EntityCollection is from the  Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll in v6.0.0.0.
Also the documentation is using the RetrieveMultiple method.

Do you have some suggestions or is this not supported and the online suggestions are misleading?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is a bit misleading.

You get that error with `MailboxStatistics` because the entity is for internal use only.

Comment: Oh thanks, do you have a list of those entities that are only for internal use?
I got about ... 20 other entities that show the same error.
Some of them are:

Comment: principalattributeaccessmap
, systemapplicationmetadata
, userapplicationmetadata
, partnerapplication
, complexcontrol
, postregarding
, postrole

Comment: You can find a list of those entities [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328086.aspx).